# Mathjax extension for color of font

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

Following [this page](http://adereth.github.io/blog/2013/11/29/colorful-equations/), I try to set a color for a simple equation into a div container.

Here is an example on [this jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ysis81/18vyyvrk/25/)

It seems that equation (and so color) is not interpreted and I don't know how to make it rendered.

**JS :**

```
 MathJax.Hub.Config({
messageStyle: "none",
TeX: { equationNumbers: {autoNumber: "all"}},
tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']], 
displayMath: [ ['\\begin{displaymath}','\\end{displaymath}'], ['\\begin{equation}','\\end{equation}'] ],
processEscapes: true,
preview: "none"
}});

MathJax.Hub.Config({ TeX: { extensions: ["color.js"] }});
```

**HTML :**

```
<div id="containerMath">
$\definecolor{energy}{RGB}{0,0,172}
\color{energy} ax+b=c$
</div>
```

Anyone has already experimented colors for Mathjax fonts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the type of the `script` tag as `text/x-mathjax-config` where you are defining you mathjax config

eg:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({ TeX: { extensions: ["color.js"] }});
</script>
```

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/18vyyvrk/28/
**EDIT:** in the fiddle I also changed the script to load `onDomready`